# Google maps API v3 infowindow not displaying

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Can't fathom why the info window won't display on this page...

http://www.triangledesign.biz/contact-dev.php

Also noticed the google example has no info window...

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.

Code...

```
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.539104, -2.400264),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var image = 'cup-sm.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.539104, -2.400264);
    var contentString = '<div id="content" style = "width:100px;height:100px;background:white">test content</div>';


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title:"Get In Touch",
          icon: image
      });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the id="content' from your content? ids must be unique.

Comment: Works for me. Says "content" (which is not what the code above indicates, so you must have changed it).

Comment: Removed id = "content", still can't see it in any browser. Am concerned that https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple. doen't show either.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: got rid of the listener click and replaced with...$(document).ready(function(){
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });